# Displaying elements in multiple rows using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width container `<div>` that displays one or more widget `<div>`s. I want it to look like this:

[image: rows in CSS] <- grey blocks are widgets, red border is the container

Simplified, my structure in HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="widget1">1</div>
    <div id="widget2">2</div>
    <div id="widget3">3</div>
    <div id="widget4">4</div>
    <div id="widget5">5</div>
    <div id="widget6">6</div>
    <div id="widget7">7</div>
</div>
```

**Considerations**

1. Widgets will have a fixed height e.g. 100px
2. Widgets will have a fixed width e.g. 100px but they may also be a multiple of that width (plus any margins crossed - see widget 1)
3. Widgets should be spaced nicely with a margin (or similar) e.g. 10px
4. I don't know how many widgets there will be (the user can assign as many or few as they like to the container).
5. The container is a fixed width but doesn't have any "visual" styling (the red border is there for demonstration)
6. Solution has to work in modern browsers (and MSIE7) and would ideally be pure CSS.

Because of consideration *4.* I can't assign additional markup e.g. row div, classes (.first-child, .last-child) and because of *2.* `:nth-child` wouldn't work AFAIK.

**Things I've tried**

margin-left on widgets with `:first-child` setting `margin-left: 0` won't display a new row properly.

margin-right on widgets with `:last-child` setting `margin-right: 0` the first row forces the container div wider and [last-child isn't supported until MSIE9](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

equal left and right margins (e.g. margin: 0 5px 10px) forces the container wide again.

overflow - works great in my head! Not so much with either margins or padding.

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/agtb/VHXGT/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are thinking too complicated :-)

If I understand you correctly you don't need any special handling of the separate widgets. Just give the widgets an all around margin of half the spacing, and the container the same margin but negative.

```
#container {
    width: 440px;
    margin: -5px;
}

#container div {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/SGdG3/1/

Comment: I think you're right I was! With a small modification (widgets using only margin-left and margin-bottom and setting a negative margin-left on container) I can prevent the container widening and triggering a scrollbar (it's the width of my page area). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set container width 400 and the first div width 200 float left, rest width 100 float left

Comment: the problem I have is achieving the layout depicted in the image - it's the equal white margins around the floated elements but not at the sides of the container that's difficult